# Inverse Square root of a rectangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

I am trying to compute the inverse square root ($X^{-1/2}$) of a $n \times p$ matrix with $n > p$.

I was wondering if we can compute it via SVD just as we do it for square diagonalizable matrices i.e. $US^{-1/2}V$ etc.?

Or is there some other way of doing it?

I'd prefer a fast and efficient way as I have n=300,000 & p=50.

Thanks!

Comment: Of course SVD would "work" that way. The question only is what would you get, what does a square root of a rectangular matrix mean.

Answer (score 0):

SVD will work for this, exactly as you expect.  If your matrix is sparse, the [Lanczos algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm) may be better.